# URL Rewrite - remove directory name in the URL - PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the url like this:

http://localhost/public/viewbusiness.php?s=cyberbooger-web-services

into

http://localhost/viewbusiness.php?s=cyberbooger-web-services

thus removing the directory name in the url.
You noticed that the **viewBusiness.php** is located in the **public** directory.

My application is not following the MVC architecture, and not using a framework. This is a application I am doing right as I currently studying PHP.

My folder structure is like this:

-- /app

-- /public

-- index.php

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: IS your PHP file viewbuisness.php present in index.php folder as well ? or is there a sym link to public folder ? because once public is removed would nt it throw 404 ?

Comment: index.php is in the root folder while vieBusiness.php is in the public folder = root/public/viewBusiness.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ $1/public/$2 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: .htaccess must be saved into what directory? root or inside the public folder?

Comment: I placed it in the root folder, but no avail.